# Non commutative group of order 51

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a group, $G$, has order 51 then it must have an element, $a$ of order 3 and another element, $ b$, of order 17. If $G$ were abelian, one can easily deduce that $ab$ generates $G$ which is therefore cyclic. But what can be said if $G$ is not abelian?

Comment: There is no non-abelian group of order 51. By Sylow counting, there can only be one subgroup of order 3 and one subgroup of order 17. Since these subgroups are unique, they are normal, so $G$ is the direct product $\langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$. Since both factors are abelian, so is $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bungo

Answer (score 1):

To go a few details into the reasoning above , by Sylow's first theorem, since $51 = 3 \times 17$, we get that there are subgroups of order $3$ and $17$. Furthermore, note that the number of such $3$-Sylow subgroups is given by $3k+ 1$ ,where $k$ is some number, such that $3k+1$ divides $17$. Clearly, it follows that $k=0$ (and similarly for $17$-Sylow subgroups), and therefore, the $3$-Sylow subgroup and the $17$-Sylow subgroup are both normal. So $G$ is a direct product of two coprime cyclic groups and is therefore cyclic itself.

Note that this generalizes to any group of order $pq$, where $p < q$ and $q \not \equiv 1 \mod p$.

Comment: You made a typo : you meant $k=0$

Comment: Ah, that's right.  Thank you. Also, $+1$ to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without using Sylow's theorem, you can notice simply by Cauchy's theorem that there's an element of order $17$, say $b$ in $G$. Since $[G: \langle b\rangle] = 3$ is the smallest prime dividing $G$, $\langle b \rangle$ is normal in $G$.

We then have the short exact sequence $$1\to \langle b\rangle \to G \to G/\langle b\rangle \to 1$$

$G/\langle b\rangle$ has order $3$, and there's $a\in G$ of order $3$, $a\notin \langle b\rangle$. So the sequence splits. However, $3\land 16 = 1$, so there's no nontrivial morphism $G/\langle b\rangle \to Aut(\langle b\rangle)$, so the fact that the sequence splits shows that $G$ is a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$: it is $\mathbb{Z}/51\mathbb{Z}$ and is thus abelian.

(You can generalize this to groups of order $pq$, $p<q$ and $p$ doesn't divide $q-1$, $p,q$ primes)